# How do I force PHP Mongo driver to return results as objects instead of array

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP Mongo extension to connect to Mongo DB server. The problem is that even though I insert the values into Mongo DB as objects, I am always getting the results in Array format when I use `find` or `findOne` in PHP. I found it really ugly and hacky.

Is there a way to make PHP retain the original structure as it is in Mongo DB ?

Comment: have you tried json_decode on the array?

Comment: @amof It is already decoded automatically when I retrieve it.

Comment: you said it already returned results in array? take a look at these examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same problem as raw JSON has in PHP, which is why [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) has an option to get returned results as array (defaulting being an object).

Currently (version 1.3.7 and 1.4.0-dev) do not have such option.
We have talked about adding that option, and I just created a [tracking ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-777) for it now, which will potentially be fixed later in the 1.4.x series.